# Unable to link TMS components after compiling in Debug Mode for Test Complete Software in C++ Builder XE5 project

Tags: c++builder, testcomplete, tms, c++builder-xe5

We are trying to set up our xe5 project with TMS components.

We have tried following steps from the [smart bear website](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/74037/) with no luck:

- Opened up the `tmscxe5group.groupproj`
- Selected `Project->Options->Packages`
- Proceeded to remove the TMS Component Pack, TMS Component Pack design time support, TMS Component pack Extra, TMS Component pack Wizards and TMS TAdvStringGrid Excel Support packages from our project
- Successfully Installed `tmscxe5.bpl`, `tmsexcxe5.bpl`, `tmsdecxe5.bpl` and `tmsxlscxe5.bpl`
- Opened up our project
- We then made sure our project options matched the project options in the smart bear tutorial from the URL above
- We then edited Runtime Packages->Runtime Package import libraries in the options menu for all of our files in the project manager to include the names of all of the installed tmscomponents from the previous part (tmscxe5.bpl, tmsexcxe5.bpl, tmsdecxe5.bpl and tmsxlscxe5.bpl). We did this after selecting the all configurations option in the Target Drop down menu
- We built our project and observed the associated libraries through windows process explorer
- None of the TMScomponents are included when running the executable and Debug information is still not found when running Test Complete

Any help understanding what we are doing wrong while trying to link the TMS Components to our debug project would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: TMS has it's own tech. support via email or forum. Better to ask there.